# Images flickering when hovered over?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please see this page: http://georgewoolfe.com/new-website/works.html

There are three images that change the colour on hover using the following CSS:

```
#chorus {
    background: url('../images/work-icons/icon-chorus to size BW.jpg');
    height: 85px;
    left: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 86px;
    width: 113px;
    display: block;
}

span:hover #chorus {
    background: url('../images/work-icons/chorus-icon to size.jpg');
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

When they are first hovered they flicker slightly. How can I prevent this initial flickering?

Comment: rather than linking to an 'external' website, how about using something like jsfiddle? (as you error ***only*** occurs on first hover)?

Comment: i dont realy understand what you mean with "flickering". i hover over it and it changes the color. which i guess is what they should do

Comment: can you please go with jsfiddle? as it would be easy to do testing, still change display: block; to display: inherit; may be it gonna help you\

Comment: If you mean the delay in showing the first time you hover, its because you're downloading the "colored" image for the first time when you hover... After that it gets cached...

Comment: Either preload the images or make it one big image and then shift the background on hover.