# Can I write form tags in other form tags?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, underscore.js

Can i write form tag in other form tag? Actually my requirement is to implement the file upload. Here we are using the underscore js template and we are keep all items into one form. 
after adding the upload code inside form i am not able to complete the file upload functionality. Please have a look my code below code.

```
<script type="text/template"><div class="container"></br></br>
<% _.each(forms, function(form){ %>
<form id="<%= formId(form) %>" name="<%= formCaption(form) %>">
    <%_.each(form.layout.grid,  function(grid){
         _.each(grid.columns, function(column){ 
            var dcLayoutInfo = dataControlLayoutInfo(column);
            var dcInfo = dataControlInfo(form.datacontrols,dcLayoutInfo.datacontrol);
            var datacontrols = formDatacontrols(form) 
             _.each(datacontrols, function(datacontrol){ 
                if(dcInfo.id == datacontrol.id){%>
                    <div class="form-group"><div class="row datacontrol" id="<%=datacontrolId(datacontrol)%>">
                    <% _.each(datacontrol.layout.grid, function(grid){ 
                     _.each(grid.columns, function(column){ 
                            var datatypes = datacontrolDatatypes(datacontrol);
                            var datatypeLayoutInfo = dataTypeLayoutInfo(column);
                            var datatypeInfo = dataTypeInfo(datatypes,datatypeLayoutInfo.datatype); 
                        if("label" == datatypeInfo.dataType){ %>
                            <div class="col-sm-2" ><label class="input-sm control-label lableId" id="<%= datatypeInfo.id %>" data-type="label"><%=datatypeInfo.caption%></label></div>
                        <%}else if("text" == datatypeInfo.dataType){%>
                            <!--div class="col-sm-8 p-r-0"><input id="<%= datatypeInfo.id %>" class="form-control input-sm selected datatype" type="<%= datatypeInfo.type %>" data-type="text"/></div-->
                            <div class="col-sm-5"><input id="<%= datatypeInfo.id %>" type="<%= datatypeInfo.type %>" class="form-control input-sm selected datatype" data-type="text"></div>
                        <%}else if("progress" == datatypeInfo.dataType){%>
                            <!--div class="col-sm-10"><div class="progress slider"><div id="<%= datatypeInfo.id %>" class="progress-bar datatype" data-type="progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:25%"/>
                            </div></div>-->
                        <div class="col-md-5 m-t-4"><div class="slider-container"><input id="<%= datatypeInfo.id %>" type="<%= datatypeInfo.type %>" class="input-slider datatype" data-slider-min="-20" data-slider-max="150" data-slider-value="0" data-type="progress"></div></div>
                        <!--date control -->
                        <%}else if("datepicker" == datatypeInfo.dataType && datatypeInfo.range==false){%>
                            <div class="col-sm-1 m-b-15 m-r-5"><div class="input-icon datetime-pick date-only"><input placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="<%= datatypeInfo.type %>" class="form-control input-sm datatype" id="<%= datatypeInfo.id %>" data-type="datepicker" range="<%= datatypeInfo.range %>">
                                    <span class="add-on-right "><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span></div></div><div class="col-sm-1 m-b-15">
                                        <div class="input-icon datetime-pick time-only"><input placeholder="HH:MM" type="<%= datatypeInfo.type %>" class="form-control input-sm datatype" data-format="hh:mm:ss" id="<%= datatypeInfo.id %>">
                            <span class="add-on-right "><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span></div></div>
                        <%}else if("datepicker" == datatypeInfo.dataType && datatypeInfo.range==true){%>
                        <div class="col-sm-1 m-b-15 m-r-5"><div class="input-icon datetime-pick date-only">
                            <input placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="<%= datatypeInfo.type %>" class="form-control input-sm datatype" id="<%= datatypeInfo.id %>" data-type="datepicker" range="<%= datatypeInfo.range %>">
                                <span class="add-on-right "><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span></div></div><div class="col-sm-1 m-b-15">
                                    <div class="input-icon datetime-pick time-only"><input placeholder="HH:MM" type="<%= datatypeInfo.type %>" class="form-control input-sm" data-format="hh:mm:ss" id="<%= datatypeInfo.id %>">
                                <span class="add-on-right "><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span></div></div>
                            <div><span class="add-on-right  pull-left"><i class="fa fa-minus p-t-10"></i></span></div><div class="col-sm-1 m-b-15 pull-left">
                        <div class="input-icon datetime-pick date-only"><input placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="<%= datatypeInfo.type %>" class="form-control input-sm enddate" id="<%= datatypeInfo.id %>" data-type="datepicker">
                            <span class="add-on-right "><i class="fa fa-calendar" id="calendar"></i></span></div></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-1 m-b-15"><div class="input-icon datetime-pick time-only"><input placeholder="HH:MM" type="<%= datatypeInfo.type %>" class="form-control input-sm " data-format="hh:mm:ss" id="<%= datatypeInfo.id %>">
                        <span class="add-on-right"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></span></div></div>
                        <!--category control -->    
                        <%}else if("category" == datatypeInfo.dataType){%>
                            <div class="btn-group datatype" id="<%= datatypeInfo.id %>" data-type="category">
                                <% _.each(datatypeInfo.values, function(categoryObj){ %>
                                    <li class="onselectedCategory btn btn-gr-gray btn-sm m-r-20 ctg" data-id="<%= categoryObj.value %>"><%= categoryObj.value %></li>
                                <% }); %>                                   
                            </div>
                        <!--contact control -->
                        <%}else if("contactpicker" == datatypeInfo.dataType){%>
                            <div class="col-md-10"><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span><input type="<%= datatypeInfo.type %>" class="form-control datatype" id="<%= datatypeInfo.id %>" name="<%= datatypeInfo.id %>" data-type="text"/><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></span></div></div>
                        <!--category list control -->
                        <%}else if("fieldset" == datatypeInfo.dataType){%>
                            <div class="col-md-5"><div class="container datatype" data-type="fieldset" id="<%= datatypeInfo.id %>">
                            <select type="<%= datatypeInfo.type %>" class="form-control multiselect btn-group"  id="categoryList" style="width: 400px;" multiple="multiple">
                                <% _.each(datatypeInfo.values, function(categoryObj){ %>
                                    <optgroup>
                                        <option value="<%= datatypeInfo.values %>"><%= categoryObj.value %></option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                <% }); %>   
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <%}else if("file" == datatypeInfo.dataType){%>
                        <div class="col-sm-9 fileupload fileupload-new input-icon selected datatype" id="<%= datatypeInfo.id %>" data-provides="fileupload" data-type="file">
                            <form id="upload" name="upload" action="api/v1/resources" method="POST" type="<%= datatypeInfo.type %>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <span class="btn btn-file btn-sm btn-alt">
                                    <span class="fileupload-new p-l-15">Add Image...</span>
                                        <span class="fileupload-exists p-l-15">Change</span>
                                    <input id="file" type="file" name="file"/><br>
                                <input id="json" type="hidden" name="json"> 
                            <span class="add-on p-t-0">
                        <i class="icon"><b>&#61697;</b></i>
                    </span>
                </span>
                    <span class="fileupload-preview"></span>
                        <a href="#" class="close close-pic fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">
    </a>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm submit" id="imageUpload">Upload</button>
</form>
    <div id="message"></div>
        <div id="resource"></div>
    </div>
    <%}});  
    });%>   
</div></div>
    <%}     
});
    });
});
});%>
</br>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div align="center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="itemSave"><i class="fa fa-check"/>  Submit</button>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button id="cancel" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary backToRecodDetails"><i class="fa fa-times"/> Cancel</button>
        <div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input id="hidden_appid" type="hidden" value= "<%=id%>" data-appname="<%=caption%>">  
  <input id="hidden_spaceid" type="hidden" value= "<%=spaceId%>">   
</form>
```

Comment: No. You can not nest forms. It's in the specification. WHY u want to Nest forms ? #WHY?

Comment: In my case designer can design the page their own way using data controls. So here file upload also one of the data control. all the data controls are in same form.here we are using rest api in server side and client side we using underscore js template, backbone and marionette js frame works.

Answer (score 4):

No. You can not nest forms. It's in [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element).

> Content model: Flow content, but with no form element descendants.

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird no. An answer should be the answer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , but WHY OP wants to Nest forms ? #WHY?

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird that is a good question. Should be a comment!

Comment: @MikeSmithDev yes its comment , my ans is comment,

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird If you would like to ask the OP some questions about why they want this functionality then you can leave them as comments on the question, and give a fuller answer when you have more details about the OPs requirements. As it stands though, this is a perfectly valid answer to the OPs, frankly rather poor, question.

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird He asked us about his attempted solution instead of what his problem was (whatever led him to think he needed to nest forms). Perhaps once he sees he can't nest forms, he'll ask a new question about his actual problem. I [put answers in comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404711/images-flickering-when-hovered-over#comment41458597_26404711) too but in this case it would likely just lead to a new question.